# Acrescentar elementos a uma página Web sem recarregar

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer um sistema para listar registros de uma tabela no banco de dados de forma que, assim que eu adicionar um novo registro, ele automaticamente apareça na listagem.

Eu tenho o sistema todo pronto só que em PHP, mas não aparece o novo registro automaticamente-- eu tenho dar um refresh na pagina para que ele seja exibido.

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso com JavaScript? O conhecimento que tenho em JavaScript é bem básico.

Comment: Com ajax você pode recolher essas informações e acrescenta-lá sem recarregar a página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função setInterval do JavaScript, para de tempos em tempos seja realizada uma requisição AJAX que recupera os dados do banco.

Se você quer algo mais instantâneo, você pode usar React.